# settings.json based on SSH host on VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

In vscode settings.json, a setting similar to this is possible:

```json
"[python]":  {
    "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false
},
```

This applies only to python files.

Let's say I have the following settings.json,

```json
"remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {
        "ubuntupc": "linux",
    },
```

and I want to apply some settings to the remote.SSH.remotePlatform > ubuntupc scope.

So, something similar to the below would be desired:

```json
"[remotePlatform]": {
  "[ubuntupc]":  {
      "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false
  },
}
```

So, for example, I can apply custom css configs (e.g. change the header color based on the host).

Is it possible? Thanks.